# Read k8s secrets as env varaible in Java spring application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have to pass env variables in JAVA SpringBoot Application.

I have created k8s secrets. I am passing them in k8s deployment YAML as env variables USER_NAME and USER_PWD.

But How to read these env variables in the application.properties file.
I have tried ${USER_NAME} but it's not working.

Ex. from application.properties file.

`spring.datasource.username=${USER_NAME}`

Comment: This is working only if the property has be manipulate under spring boot property source. However after you create the k8s secret, all this still not yet manipulate in the spring property source yet.

Comment: And yet it seems correct what you are doing. Log into your container and check whether the environment variable really exists

Comment: This would help https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, It is solved now.

I needed to pass the variables while running the JAR as well.

Ex. from application.properties file.

`spring.datasource.username=${USER_NAME}`

and in Dockerfile

`ENTRYPOINT exec java -DUSER_NAME=$USER_NAME -DUSER_PWD=$USER_PWD -jar jar-name.jar`

Comment: It would be beneficial to upvote user8794331's answer or accept it if you find it useful.

Comment: @Nick I have not tried setup using his answer so I cannot confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Deployment yml should be like this

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: 
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
        env:
         - name: spring.datasource.password
           valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
             name: your-secret-name
             key: your-secret-key
```

Kubernetes will add your spring.datasource.password and its value to your pod environment variable.

To make Spring boot use it you should add the property spring.datasource.password in your application.properties or application.yml.